# retrieve last record of a filed with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to retrieve the last record in a field?

for instance I've 5 record of uId

1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.

how to retrieve the last record?

Comment: Your question is hard to interpret. Please use the following format: - required behavior, - received behavior, - problem and as such question. In your current question especially the first part is missing; what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables in relational databases *by definition* have no inherent ordering.  So, there is no "last" row.  There is no "first" row.  That is, unless you define some other column to specify the ordering.  Typically, such a column would be an auto-incremented id or creation date field.

You can get the *largest* value easily in a couple of ways:

```
select max(uid)
from table t;
```

or

```
select t.*
from table t
order by uid desc
limit 1;
```

A field with a name like `uid` should be an auto-incremented id, so the largest value may be what you are really looking for.